# How display JSON output in html page using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

This is how I made API request using Python request :

```
mainurl = 'http://gw.api.alibaba.com/openapi/param2/2/portals.open/api.listPromotionProduct/'
api_key = '9420'
fields = '?fields=productId,productUrl,productTitle,salePrice,originalPrice,imageUrl'
payload = {
        'keywords': "women",
        'pageSize': "40",
        'language': 'en',
        'sort': 'volumeDown',
        'isFreeShip': 'y',
        'isFavorite': 'y',
        'pageNo': "1"
    }
urlx = mainurl + api_key + fields
r = requests.get(urlx, params=payload)
print(r.content)
```

when run it returns long JSON outputs :

```
{'result': {'commissionRate': '5.00%', 'originalPrice': 'US $1.21', ......}, 'currentPageNum': 0, 'errorCode': 20010000, 'totalPageNum': 0}
```

and this is how I try to make an API request using JQuery :

```html
## index.html ##
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="orders">

    </div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
## main.js ##

$(function (){

    var $orders = $('#orders');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://gw.api.alibaba.com/openapi/param2/2/portals.open/api.listPromotionProduct/9420?fields=productUrl,originalPrice,productTitle&keywords=women',
        success: function(orders){
            $.each(orders, function(i, order){
                $orders.append('<li> products :' + order.totalResults + '</li>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I got this result in my browser :

products :5291514

This is the JSON output :

```
{"result":{"totalResults":5275965,"products":[{"productTitle":"S-XL Plus Size Tunic Autumn ...}
```

How can display `productTitle` in my html page ?

Comment: You're fetching different fields and not passing any payload. Why would you expect the same results as from your python script?

Comment: You've got an error code - good for you! Have you researched (in the API documentation) what it means?

Comment: Url not the same. Where do you see `keywords=women` in your url?

Comment: The undefined is coming from your order.result object in your orders.append line. I suggest you look into debugging within the browser and inspect that object, and compare orders.result to the json you think you're sending from your python.

Comment: @ Andy Stagg I've re-phrased my question and fixed the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question well, this is what you wanted to show?

```
$.each(orders, function(i, order){
    $orders.append('<li> products :' + order.products[0].productTitle + '</li>');
});
```